# Can I avoid reflection in this case?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have these class hierarchy :

```
public abstract class Parent {
}

public class A : Parent {
    public void Update() { }
}

public class B : Parent {
    public void Update() { }
}

public class C : Parent {
    public void Update() { }
    public void Update(bool force) { }

}
```

As you can see, all descendant of `Parent` have an Update method, with no parameter.

I want to create an utility class that can work with any kind of `Parent` object and call `Update` at the end of the process. I am sure the Update method will be implemented, so I wrote this code :

```
public class ParentUtilities {
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> g_UpdateMethods = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>{
        { typeof(A), typeof(A).GetMethod("Update", new Type[] {})},
        { typeof(B), typeof(B).GetMethod("Update", new Type[] {})},
        { typeof(C), typeof(C).GetMethod("Update", new Type[] {})}
    };

    public static void DoSomething(Parent p)
    {
          CalculateTheMeaningOfTheLife(p);             

          g_UpdateMethods[p.GetType()].Invoke(p, null);
    }
}
```

As **I don't have control over the class hierarchy (it's from a 3rd party assembly)**. I can only change the utility class. How can I avoid such tweak ?

As I'm sticked to .Net 3.5 SP1, I can't use dynamic.

Comment: as I said, I don't have control over the class hierarchy (it's from a 3rd party assembly). The Parent and descendants class are in a 3rd party assembly, but my utility class is from a code I'm writing.

Comment: You can probably construct delegates to avoid the reflection's invoke.

Comment: @leppie: do you mean something like `private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<Parent>> = new Dictionary<Type, Action> { { typeof(T), (p)=> ((T)p).Update() }}` ?

Comment: If you don't want to change anything in the calling code, I assume it is easier to either go with LukeH solution or just go with the reflection, I can see you are caching everything, I assume that is efficient enough that it probably wont be the problem.

Comment: @SteveB: That is one way :) I was thinking of using `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, but the end result should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's just a known, (very) small set of child classes then you could do something like this:

```
public class ParentUtilities
{
    public static void DoSomething(Parent p)
    {
        CalculateTheMeaningOfTheLife(p);

        var a = p as A;
        if (a != null)
        {
            a.Update();
            return;
        }

        var b = p as B;
        if (b != null)
        {
            b.Update();
            return;
        }

        var c = p as C;
        if (c != null)
        {
            c.Update();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm starting to think this can be the simplest solution (there is actually 3 direct descendants)

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do without touching those classes is to create your own interface `IUpdateable` and then create a new parallel hierarchy of your own as in

```
interface IUpdateable
{
    void Update();
}

public class A : Original.A, IUpdateable {}
```

If you can then use your own leaf classes instead of the original ones, you can write the method as accepting an `IUpdateable` parameter. But while consuming your own classes is not very difficult (`using` [alias directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can help), *producing* them is not so easy (you need to interpose custom code after each call to the original library that creates any instances of the original classes, and if that instance is typed as `Parent` you are back to square one).

Don't forget to persecute the author of the original code on sight as well.

Comment: In my very simple example, this should perfectly works. however, I'm actually accessing dozens of properties, methods, etc. This would require to either wrap each property, or publish the inner original A. That will create more problem that it will solve,I think

Comment: @SteveB: You don't need to wrap anything actually. Just defining the interface would be enough, the implementors would be otherwise "empty" classes.

Comment: Please, note that this will only work if you are the one who instantiates A, B and C classes.. if any of them is created by a factory method or the like, this will fail.

Comment: Jon, using your method, I have to change my utility class argument from Parent to IUpdatable, right? If I do that, all calls to my utility method will have to be changed (`ParentUtility.DoSomethin(new A(myOriginalA))`). Then, within the method itself, I won't be able to access other methods and properties of A. To solve this, I have to store the original instance in my wrapped instance, or wrap all interesting members. This will lead to a greater complexity for callers, just to avoid a small call of reflection.

Comment: @SteveB: Yes, and that's why it would only be sane if you could "intercept" the creation of `A`, `B`, `C` and create your own `A`, `B`, `C` that derive from (not wrap!) the originals. Which is not definitely possible, and is definitely impossible if you get the instances from a factory method as AhHatem says.

Comment: The original instances are returnes by the 3rd party app, so I can't intercept its creation unfortunately. Still an interesting approach

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper class with a well-defined interface implementation.

**Usage**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        IUpdatable wrapper = new AWrapper(a);
        wrapper.Update(); // prints A.Update
    }
}
```

**Wrapper class and interface**

```
interface IUpdatable
{
    void Update();
}


public abstract class Parent { }

public class A : Parent
{
    public void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Update");
    }
}

public class AWrapper : IUpdatable
{
    public A Inner { get; private set; }
    public AWrapper(A a)
    {
        Inner = a;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Inner.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: this code will require all calls to the DoSomething method to create a wrapped instance instead of simply passing the original object. I can accept a bit of complexity in the utility method, but not from the calling code (it's an utility method after all, which purpose is to simplify things)

Answer (score 0):

Create an interim class called UpdatableParent which DOES include an Update() method, and derive all the other classes from it. Then use UpdateableParent as the type of the DoSomething() argument.

Comment: I can't change neither parent class nor descendant (A,B,C)